# Unity Google Mobile Ads Mediatiod MoPub build error Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, mopub

I added Google mobile ads. After adding MoPub mediation package, it started giving build error.

iOS error: [image]

Android Error: [image]

Answer (score 0):

the errors mentioned that you don't have swift bridging in your project to create swift bridging follow below steps.

1. create new file in xcode project
2. select swift file remain file name `File.swift`
3. after create swift file xcode will ask for `create bridging` tap on create bridge

after create bridging now try to build project

Comment: What you said only applies to the iOS part, but I think the problem is in the MoPub package. Is this solution sure to work?

Comment: it should work because MoPub package is in swift , and your old packages also supports objective-c, try to implement swift bridge and write me its working or not